# Is there a web service that performs object recognition using an artificial neural network?

Tags: neural-network

I'd like to have a program call a web service that performs object recognition using a neural network.  Is there a web service that can do this?

Comment: The project in the web page below will create the web service.  It will also create a web site that is used to test and demonstrate the web service.       http://www.indiegogo.com/VOR

Answer (score 0):

There is the ["Google Prediction API"](https://developers.google.com/prediction/) available as a web service - although there is little information on what models they use.

Answer (score 0):

Google has a service called "Search By Image".  It's not just a tineye clone, but rather will give a suggestion for the type of object in the image you upload or provide URL for.  It's not clear whether or not they use a neural network although Google researchers have been known to work on machine learning of course (like the recent stacked autoencoder that classified cats, human faces, bodies etc).

http://www.google.com/insidesearch/features/images/searchbyimage.html

Their description from help:

> How it works
>
> Google uses computer vision techniques to match your image to other images in the Google Images index and additional image collections. From those matches, we try to generate an accurate "best guess" text description of your image, as well as find other images that have the same content as your search image. Your search results page can show results for that text description as well as related images."

Here's an example where it correctly classified this image as ["1 cat"](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi%3aAMhZZiuqpP3ktkOMTZikHIb14BmYnaW4kU8FayA-39e36m2LEfUVPtqLBCrbbw8e0hmCj2FxssA3gwEXAhteyW_1XMhvLXjeoPJrTAwHptIUZo_15Rx2PHqdaCwAVqSo8iYRz9dVCZsLyHOMiAIAFg2n8lBkD4qrtPbmax_19ZEApD05QDZoBxNcTuPob--HFu5-jldrImCKvCcc3tvu_1QReYWlKXx2Dbtx_1B47yqnNUMeyC9s1CC94dOOu3EgQpmSMMbDizSBoNlT1jmpDopt-yXF-JBll744FmaviH0y2MimNafERx92TTAfnivmDyBBPdFfjjka3EclaWbGs1YQzKC89NFuNSMFmIMkWcT7JVfUom-X6dxO5UaZ4HNGwowjqpxxa03U_1Jxm25D9y2ur2pD1f445iwaDMsMdF7HsfJzCP0N0hPefvjsBXH5LXyNHWpNHKDe4ZiKUOuC9BmmLbGmi82KZmBf71QN6Halth9nTFw9vSM9KAET-TichBJAqWt8rwM13nt512tVW7-dXkJVwYO5nUKb_1y6Kh0OVe9L5hAyDWFIe_13nlf6iOAmMezVnwiq0aa1LYWhiViq303tKXhQUOBUrTNhYTpwXXczv0EcUityfdx8sIjes1GGNPNAhRprs62rI71tE713ORI7mjRjcGDZYXs4DsG3HAvUvR0ktQxRfErfl8WPvm7J205PqyScn14Ru-xaLOdP_1KjOuK807AW7aa9D5ta4je3eQaPYCkCSLfcvpjYzK0fL29RpaqOZEKvqouCCEQ4rt2_1GH7I51yKn112Pnz9IolJ2_1_1SSur2kkWJpLJRs6XerI6KSDR0LX5ZPEK_1NI5WD8uKVkoJ3DN4O65L6d-J8pnk6yaQZO5oPnNOy1uToRFd3b3P8xTh03nyI9obAkZ8IfxkoRCpBmgUG-gQReW5K0Y-9xjQL7oh1gqrDkw5kGcpS0m-Rfx8bu3M4_1DOKhqMaaMo-l_1IODHrWzfFRNGL8029Cdy6ySAmx20VMip9jcpRPjn1P7dOaabaOI0IHdtwo5UeQ4QY26f2vUF5SUyVussM5pXMH2yureKULp5pFBycVTENkfNm3muxzjk1zzmngeCzBHqF0vwHgqZDdmWx-lVjo11u_1u8eP0zIaZaMRL20U2QqDPqOlPzsICHDLUQhWL7QMuLsJxGjwROOO9fWGiWIE_1jmzercL43RAtDzIsHuU8bz6-Mkjo2HvD03kuiESMtnnHOFtSHyQ_1fQUGMMm3K_1POUR8fc5UHfsbIo1WTApFlfq-btaTtmnA6wGE2_1ojDK1Y-fzcw8tFvpiK70qxWcC3-XsE4RMllDhv2vlfUHMDFrE8LRNRsyedgPU2i_1SiHlXUx6jPlfOlnrKzKPBiC_10ADF8tht2Srt0vAQooEulWf6u2kHQib1s6OxbOMExErQ219cA0BeZhIuEH729oGaE9jQLnIb_1Z1U7bfSM&num=10&hl=en&safe=off&bih=1032&biw=1529)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Strong Steam](http://strongsteam.com):

> StrongSteam is an AppStore of artificial intelligence and 
>   data mining APIs to let you pull interesting information 
>   out of images, video and audio.